# AES192 Encryption with Node.js

Tags: node.js, encryption

I have a Node.js API. It has to make a SOAP call to a "parent" API that includes one item encrypted via AES-192 (ECB) with a key. I'm trying to use the native crypto library, but the value I'm getting doesn't match the value they're expecting.

From the spec:

> Encryption of the [string] is done using AES (NIST FIPS-197) 192 bit encryption using Hex encoding. It uses the ECB feedback mode with PKCS5Padding. Neither IV nor salting is used.

Frankly, I had to look most of that up and it still hasn't helped. Aside from occasionally md5'ing something that didn't need to be truly secure or perhaps sha'ing something that did, I've never done much with encryption so I'm a little stuck.  Here's what I have at this point:

```
var cipher = require( 'crypto' ).createCipher( 'aes192', datasources.api.auth.encryptionKey )
cipher.update( data.encryptable )
cipher.final( 'hex' )
```

I've tried a number of variants of input and output encoding in `cipher.update()`, but I haven't been able to match the value that they're expecting.

Can anyone more familiar with this stuff point me in the right direction? At this point, I've exhausted my own knowledge and have digressed into trial and error.

**UPDATE**

More of what I have so far:

```
var crypto  = require( 'crypto' );
var cipher  = crypto.createCipher( 'aes-192-ecb', datasources.api.auth.encryptionKey );
var crypted = cipher.update( 'DSS9676155', 'binary', 'hex' );
crypted     += cipher.final( 'hex' );

console.log( 'CRYPTED:  ' + crypted );
console.log( 'EXPECTED: 72989ABBE3D58AE582EF0EA669EDE521' );
```

Interestingly (?), I get the same `crypted` value (164fb25126c444031780c78d098fa877) no matter what combination of input and output encoding values I send to the `update()` method. That seems like a clear indication that I've done something very wrong, but I can't see it.

**UPDATE**

Just received this from the API provider. They encrypt the text using Python as follows:

```
import sys
import chilkat

crypt = chilkat.CkCrypt2()

password = "thisIsWhereTheKeyGoes"

crypt.put_CryptAlgorithm("aes")
crypt.put_CipherMode("ECB")
crypt.put_KeyLength(192)
crypt.SetEncodedKey(password,"base64")

crypt.put_EncodingMode("hex")
text = "The string to be encrypted"

encText = crypt.encryptStringENC(text)

print encText
```

I've updated my code as follows:

```
var crypto    = require( 'crypto' );
var base64pwd = new Buffer( datasources.api.auth.encryptionKey ).toString( 'base64' );
var cipher    = crypto.createCipher( 'aes-192-ecb', base64pwd );
var crypted   = cipher.update( 'DSS9676155', 'utf8' );
crypted       += cipher.final( 'hex' );

console.log( 'CRYPTED:  ' + crypted );
console.log( 'EXPECTED: 72989ABBE3D58AE582EF0EA669EDE521' );
```

I still a different result from what's expected. Again, I've tried several variants of in/output encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever it's worth, I never got Node.js to kick back the same value that the provider expected. I ended up writing a Python script using the same process they use and had my Node app call it. It's a total hack, but at least it works.

Just wanted to put a wrapper on this question so it wasn't left open forever.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
var crypto  = require( 'crypto' );
var cipher  = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', DATA_CRYPT_KEY, DATA_CRYPT_IV);
var crypted = cipher.update(JSON.stringify(result),'utf8','hex');
crypted    += cipher.final('hex');

res.send(crypted);
```

Comment: This would _appear_ to include IV which is not part of the spec. Am I reading that wrong? I did try `aes-192-ebc` as the algorithm, but it spits out an unknown algorithm error.

Comment: yeah, I just posted a piece of code I use in production - it uses ads-256 with IV. The only difference (apart from algorithm) I see is that you don't save result of encryption anywhere, do you?

Comment: No, I'm not saving the result. I'm just consuming it at that moment. Part of my problem is that I typo'd the algorithm (-ebc instead of -ecb). I've fixed that and am soldiering on. I haven't tried you in/output encodings yet.

Comment: I've updated my question so that my code looks more like yours and with some additional details about what I see after trying every permutation if in/output encoding to the `update` method. I appreciate the extra set of eyeballs.

Comment: If you run the following command `echo -n "DSS9676155" | openssl enc -aes-192-ecb -pass pass:mykey -nosalt` it returns the very same result as if you make cipher.final with `'binary'` parameter. However if you replace `'binary'` with `'hex'`, result would not be the same as if you do a hex digest after openssl command...

Comment: But if you use `echo -n "DSS9676155" | openssl enc -aes-192-ecb -pass pass:mykey -nosalt | openssl base64`, it produces the very same result as `cipher.final('base64');`.

Comment: You kind of lost me there. I'm going to need a few minutes to wrap my head around this one...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23792/discussion-between-kovpas-and-rob-wilkerson)

Comment: If you don't mind taking yet another look, I've updated the question with the Python code used by the API provider to encrypt strings. I'm not familiar with this library, but nothing sticks out to me as being radically different in terms of implementation steps (for whatever that's worth).

Comment: For me it looks the same. The only thing I noticed while played with `CkCrypt2` is that in `SetEncodedKey` you provide ENCODED password, so it decodes during cyphering. So you don't need to encode your password to base64 in nodejs implementation. However I still get different results... Probably your provider could provide example on any other language, without using CkCrypt2?

Comment: Well, at least it's not just me. I appreciate the sanity check. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[`crypto.createCipher()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) was confusing because it *derived* the key from the provided password:

> The implementation of `crypto.createCipher()` *derives* keys using the OpenSSL function `EVP_BytesToKey` with the digest algorithm set to *MD5, one iteration, and no salt*. The lack of salt allows dictionary attacks as the same password always creates the same key. The low iteration count and non-cryptographically secure hash algorithm allow passwords to be tested very rapidly.

It is deprecated now.

You should have tried [`crypto.createCipheriv()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options) instead. In ECB mode just provide an empty buffer as the IV.

```
var crypto  = require( 'crypto' );
var cipher  = crypto.createCipheriv( 'aes-192-ecb', encryptionKey, Buffer.alloc(0) );
var buf1 = cipher.update( Buffer.from(data) );
var buf2 = cipher.final();
var crypted = Buffer.concat([buf1, buf2]);
```